# What do you think about this code for functions that take both pool and transaction?

Tags: rust

*I'm trying sqlx for the first time these days, sorry if this is a dumb question.*

I'm writing a function that I want to take both `PgPool` and `Transaction<Postgres>`.

I'm using the below (SIMPLIFIED) code:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Default, sqlx::FromRow)]
pub struct PgPlayer {
    pub id: String,
    pub created_at: time::OffsetDateTime,
    pub updated_at: Option<time::OffsetDateTime>,
    pub name: String,
    pub team: Option<String>,
}

async fn player_delete(&self, id: &str) -> Result<()> {
  let mut tx = self.pool.begin().await?;

  let player_in_db = query_by_id(&mut tx, id).await?;

  // Do something with player_in_db here...

  delete(&mut tx, id).await?;

  tx.commit().await?;

  Ok(())
}

pub fn query_by_id<'a>(
  db: impl sqlx::PgExecutor<'a> + 'a,
  id: &'a str,
) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<PgPlayer>> + Send + 'a>> {
  Box::pin(async move {
      let player = sqlx::query_as::<_, PgPlayer>(
          r#"SELECT * FROM players WHERE id = $1"#,
      )
      .bind(id)
      .fetch_one(db)
      .await?;

      Ok(player)
  })
}

pub async fn delete<'a>(
  db: impl sqlx::PgExecutor<'a>,
  id: &str,
) -> Result<()> {
  sqlx::query(r#"DELETE FROM players WHERE id = $1"#)
      .bind(id)
      .execute(db)
      .await?;

  Ok(())
}
```

Is this good enough or **is there a better way to write it (maybe avoiding the lifetimes in `impl sqlx::PgExecutor<'a>`)?**

Comment: I see neither `PgPool` nor `Transaction<Postgres>` being used anywhere in your code.

Comment: As for the lifetimes: No, not really. `sqlx::PgExecutor` needs a specified lifetime, which would be the lifetime of the user. You *could* set it to `'static`, but this would be an unnecessary widening of the required lifetime.